# Error opening terminal: unknown. (kubectl exec pod -it bash)

Tags: bash, docker, kubernetes

Using Ubuntu 19.10 using standard GNOME terminal.

I have build a docker image with [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) using the following dockerfile (its going to be a npm diagnostic/debug command line container so not application):

```
FROM ubuntu:19.10

RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y dist-upgrade && \
    apt-get -y autoremove && \
    apt-get clean

RUN apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    nano \
    git 

ARG NODE_VERSION='12.0.0'
ARG NVM_DIR=/root
ARG NVM_VERSION='v0.35.3'

RUN curl -o- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/$NVM_VERSION/install.sh" | bash \
    && source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION
```

I have build an image and pushed it to an image registry and started it in k8s. I have the accessed the running container with:

```
kubectl exec my-app-xx25 -it bash
```

But when inside the container I cannot start e.g. `nano`:

```
root@my-app-xx25:/# nano
Error opening terminal: unknown.
```

or reset the terminal for that sake:

```
root@my-app-xx25:/# reset
reset: unknown terminal type unknown
```

`vi`/`vim` works though.

Based on:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/9299

If I do:

```
kubectl exec my-app-xx25 -it -- bash -c "export TERM=xterm && bash"
```

I can start nano just fine but seems like a messy workaround.

Notice if I run it locally with docker it works fine (starting nano, reset etc):

```
docker run -it my-image /bin/bash
```

Any suggestions to what goes on and why I need to pass `export TERM=xterm` when running `kubectl exec` and not when running `docker run` (locally)?

Comment: I built image and started container `docker run -ti stack bash` then `nano` inside container opened editor without any problem. It's seems like problem in the way of start the container. I think if you look at `env` variables, you'll see `TERM=unknown"`, so, try to add to Dockerfile  `ENV TERM=xterm` at the end of file. Anyway when I added `ENV XTERM=unknown` at the end of file, I've got the same result as  your's.

Comment: What are you using for a terminal/console?

Comment: This image doesn't seem to install any application code at all; it's just a bare Node interpreter.  What are you hoping to get by running this in Kubernetes?  (With this particular set of tooling, what are you hoping to get over just running Node on your local system?)

Comment: @DavidMaze: Need it for experimenting/debugging with npm on different nodes. @zalex: Yes `docker run` works fine. Its only `kubectl exec` thats causing problems. @Matt: GNOME terminal.

Comment: Try bash -l instead

Comment: I have tried: `kubectl exec my-app-xx25 -i -- bash` (assuming thats what you mean) but then it just hangs at the prompt and I never get into the container.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of odd that you are running nano inside a Kubernetes pod/container. Given that your `kubectl exec ...` is not a root login shell, a workaround is to put the value in your `/root/.bashrc`:

export TERM=xterm

I'd recommend you build the container with the file built-in if you are going to run this on a regular basis because if it's not then every time your pod/container restart you will have to manually modify the `/.bashrd` content.

Comment: As part of debugging inside a diag/debugging container it becomes handy to use an editor from time to time or being able to reset the console. I guess a more simple approach would be to add `ENV TERM=xterm` to the dockerfile as suggested by @zalex

Comment: Yes. It might be helpful for debugging.